# How can I make an optional named group?

Tags: regex-group

I want to catch strings in named groups. the second string is optional. If this optional string is missing my regex code not working.

```
(?<entry1>string1) (?<entry2>string2)? (?<entry3>string3)
```

How can I make the second string optional?

Answer (score 0):

If I remove the '?' at the begin of each group (what are they for? https://www.regextester.com/ does not accept them) your expression works for these strings:

```
<entry1>string1  <entry3>string3
<entry1>string1 <entry2>string2 <entry3>string3
```

The problem with your regex is that you can omit the second group expression `<entry2>string2` but not the space after that group. The following regex strings probably works as you expect it to.

```
(<entry1>string1) (<entry2>string2?) ?(<entry3>string3)
(<entry1>string1) ((<entry2>string2) )?(<entry3>string3)
```

The second string might better fit your needs but has more group expressions. Depending on if you really require the space or not you might finetune the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using ? at the beginning of each capturing group. ? means 0 or 1 occurrences of the previous match, which it doesn't mean anything in that case. As @Werner Henzer mentions, you probably having issues with the spaces.
My solution is shown below:

```
(<entry1>string1)\s*?(<entry2>string2)?\s*?(<entry3>string3)
```

which forces a match for group 1 and 3, with group 2 to be optional, and permits the use of spaces between the groups in a lazy mode.

Comment: Many Thanks. Works perfect!

Comment: @neo79 probably I need to see the string that you are trying to match